# It is correct to cast to int after dereferencing a void pointer?

Tags: c

```
void* aPtr = NULL;  // we don't yet know what it points to.
...
aPtr = &height;     // it has the address of height, but no type yet.
...
int h = (int)*aPtr; // with casting, we can now go to that address
                    // and fetch an integer value.
```

([Learn C Programming; Jeff Szuhay](https://books.google.pl/books?id=0gbuDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA262&lpg=PA262&dq=%22with%20casting,%20we%20can%20now%20go%20to%20that%20address%22&source=bl&ots=OUZrocXONA&sig=ACfU3U2cS2X1C0bSxIPrCubrF-chLILs0A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjp7PC4p7P1AhXNiv0HHVSODNEQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22with%20casting%2C%20we%20can%20now%20go%20to%20that%20address%22&f=false))

> 'with casting, we can now go [...]'

The question is - can we really?

Comment: Looks like a typo. It should be `int h = *(int *)aPtr;`.

Comment: Looks more like an error (a mistake, a blunder) than a typo.

Comment: You can't dereference a `void` pointer because it doesn't refer to a type that can be referenced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Dereferencing and Casting Void Ptr (Learn C Programming, Jeff Szuhay)
>
> 'with casting, we can now go [...]'
>
> The question is - can we really?

Yes, but the shown code doesn't do any dereferencing. Well, it *tries* to dereference a `void*` and cast the result to `int`. That's not how it should be done. You must first cast to `int*` and *then* dereference that `int*`.

```
int h = *(int*)aPtr;    // now dereferenced ok (assuming `height` is an `int`)
//      ^   ^
//      |   |
//      |  proper cast
//      |
// dereferencing the right thing
```